# Non-isomorphic curves with the same genus

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I need to show that the curves $y^7=x^2(x-1)$ and $xy^3+zx^3+yz^3=0$ are not isomorphic even if the are both of genus 3. I have tried to show that they are a quartic and a hyperelliptic curve in order to show that they are in two different class of isomorphism.
I have normalized the first one with this sequence of blow-ups and transformations:

$x=x_1y_1, y=y_1     \rightarrow x_1^3y_1-y_1^5-x_1^2=0$

$x_1=x_2y_2, y_1=y_2 \rightarrow x_2^3y_2^2-y_2^3-x_2^2=0$

$x_2=x_3y_3,y_3=y_2  \rightarrow x_3^3y_3^3-y_3-x_3^2=0$

$x_3=\frac{X_3}{Z_3},y_3=\frac{Y_3}{Z_3} \rightarrow X_3^3Y_3^3-Y_3Z_3^5-X_3^2Z_3^4=0$

$y_3'=\frac{Y_3}{X_3}, z'_3=\frac{Z_3}{X_3} \rightarrow (y'_3)^3-(y'_3)(z'_3)^5-(z'_3)^4=0$

$y_3'=y_4z_4, z'_3=z_4\rightarrow y_4^3-y_4z_4^3-z_4=0$

The last one is nonsingular but is almost exactly the other, so what is wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean birational instead of isomorphic ? The second one is a projective curve, of the field of rational functions only the constant functions are regular on the whole curve, the first one is an affine curve with $x$ non-constant regular.

Comment: What do you mean by "the last one is...almost exactly the other"? The onslaught of indices is making my head spin, but it looks like you've written it as the intersection of two surfaces in a rational threefold, so I'm not sure what you're trying to say about its relation to a plane curve (and that's not even getting into the affine/projective ambiguities mentioned in the previous comment). But to comment on your strategy, if the first curve is indeed hyperelliptic and the second is indeed smooth, then you will have shown that they are non-birational curves of genus $3$.

Comment: @reuns Yes, birational. I'm considering these two curves as two Riemann Surfaces so I'm thinking always at their projective closure.

Comment: @TabesBridges I mean that I have obtained almost the same equation and then the same Riemann Surface. I have tried to build a nonsingular model for the first with that sequence of birational morphisms and maybe there is something wrong there that I can't find.

Comment: @cartesio But you have multiple equations at the end, no? How are you comparing two curves that are presented in these different ways? And again, what do you mean by "almost the same"? Typically perturbing the equation(s) changes the birational class.

Comment: @TabesBridges oh no! I just edited, there was a little mistake.

Comment: @cartesio I'm not sure what you changed, but if it was the last equation OK, that is indeed birational to the other curve. Assuming that you have been told by a reliable source that this is not the case I would guess that you made a computation error, but this is the sort of thing that's hard to debug without documentation. You haven't indicated where any of your blowups are living, so I'm not sure how you end up with just one equation at the end. Are you repeatedly passing to some open set of the blown up plane which is itself (the open set that is) isomorphic to $\mathbb A^2$?

Comment: @Tabes Bridges, this is an exercise from Geometry of Algebraic Curves by Arbarello. Yes, I have projected each blow up on an affine plane.

Comment: Hmm, well as Sasha has shown apparently the curves *are* birational, so I guess there is a typo in ACGH.

Comment: Your computation looks correct to me. In the first three steps, the singularity is resolved. In the 4th step, you take the closure of the affine curve (defined by the 3rd equation) in $\mathbb P^2$ and in the last two steps, you localized at a different affine chart and resolved the singularity. All of these operations does not change the function field, so you are done! I'm just curious how did you find this sequence (especially step 4~6)?

Comment: @AGlearner I have just tried to resolve the singularity using blow up. I have blown up the same singularity until the affine curve is smooth then I have considered the projective closure to be sure that the points at infinity are not singular. If they are singular I localize there and I repete the same process. I'm doing it with several other curves but somethimes I have found that there are kind of cycles in which you finish without finding the normalization.

Comment: @cartesio In some sense, this process is not canonical. For example, I can close up the curve $y^7=x^2(x-1)$ in $\mathbb P^2$, so there is a singularity at infinity, then I can localize at infinity and resolve the (only) singularity on this chart, then I close up in $\mathbb P^2$ and further resolve the singularity. The resulting curve is smooth and birational to, therefore isomorphic to Klein quartic. I guess the reason that you can easily compare the equation of two curves explicitly is that Klein quartic is a plane curve. I believe this will be hard in general.

Answer (score 1):

The curve
$$
xy^3 + yz^3 + zx^3 = 0
$$
is the famous Klein quartic, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_quartic. Its automorphism group has order 168, the maximal among curves of genus 3. In particular, it has an automorphism of order 7.

On the other hand, Theorem 2(a) of [Homma, Masaaki. Automorphisms of prime order of curves. Manuscripta Math. 33 (1980/81), no. 1, 99--109] shows that a curve $C$ of genus $g \ge 2$ with an automorphism $\sigma$ of **prime** order $2g + 1$ is birational to one of the curves
$$
y^{2g+1} = x^a(x-1)^b,
$$
where $a,b \ge 1$ and $a + b \le g + 1$. Moreover, the proof of Proposition 3.1 in the paper shows that $a + b$ is the degree of a covering $f \colon C \to \mathbb{P}^1$ which is equivariant for $\sigma$.

All this applies easily to the Klein quartic. One can choose the morphism $f$ to be the projection
$$
(x,y,z) \mapsto (x:y),
$$
then its degree is 3, hence $a + b = 3$, hence (after a possible change of coordinates) the Klein quartic is birational to the curve
$$
y^7 = x^2(x-1).
$$